# How to keep 3 divs aligned in a responsive way

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have a logo with a clock in it. The idea is to have the clock's hands move to make it cool and interesting. Getting the hands to move with some jQuery was no problem. The problem is I want everything to be responsive, and when I shrink the window the hands slip away from the clock part.

To make things more fun, everything is SVG's.

Code for thought:

HTML

```
<!-- logo -->
<div class="logobox">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.svg" alt="Logo" class="logo-img" id="logo">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/clockhourhand.svg" alt="hourhand" class="logo-img" id="hour">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/clockminhand.svg" alt="minutehand" class="logo-img" id="min">
</div>
<!-- /logo -->
```

CSS

```
/* logo */
.logobox {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 80%;
height: 100%;
}

.logobox img{
margin: 0 auto;
left: 50%;
top: 10%;
}

#logo {
padding: 2em 0;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
 }

/*------------------------------------*\
    CLOCK
\*------------------------------------*/

#min, #hour {
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
width: 25%;
height: 25%;
top: 2.5em;
left: 11.8em;
}

#min {
    z-index: 2;
 }

#hour {
    z-index: 1;
 }
```

I've been messing around with this for a longer time than I care to admit, and I have to admit that I'm just not quite as clever as the hive-mind here. Thank you for the assistance.

**EDIT:**

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjcasillas/MQHJM/)

Comment: Can you please post the full code, or a representative example, of the actual SVG / HTML? Just looking at CSS is not sufficient (for me, at least)

Comment: Oops. Sorry, meant to post the HTML.

Comment: if possible make fiddle so we can playaround, apart i think making position:absolute of the logobox might solve ur issue.

Comment: Absolute positioning didn't work, but I added fiddle link. For some reason the hands aren't spinning in the fiddle. But, the main problem is still there. So solve away.

Comment: where are the 3 divs? I only see 1.

Comment: I think u need to give width:inherit; at #logo, check this fiddle if this is u expectation. (as i am bit confuses) http://jsfiddle.net/MQHJM/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to work around it using responsive media queries and changing the top and left properties to percentages.

**CSS:**

```
#min, #hour {
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
width: 25%;
height: 25%;
left: 27%;
top: 18%;
}
```